# how to set DataGridViewButtonCell BackColor using htmlColor?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

I'm struggling since 2 days to with this problem.

I have an XML file which contains Colors as htmlColor Code, in my program I have a DataGridView which is showing me the values in hexCodes, and I can click on it and change the color value with a ColorDialog and the then set the cell BackColor to the selected Color and gives me the hexCode back as new value.

sorry I cant post a picture asI dont have 10 reputaions (I'm new)

what I want is that when I open the XML file in my programm, the cells should have the BackColor of what is wrriten inside the cell.

I tried this but doesn't work :(

```
private void dgvColors_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                      DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  Theme theme = new Theme();
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Color> colour in theme.Colors)
         dgvColors.Columns["colKey"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 
                   ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colour.Value.ToString());      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the ColorTranslator(),

it works well with this version of code :

```
 private void dgvMenuColors_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) 
{ 
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMenuColors.Rows) 
{ 
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()); 
} 
}
```

:D

Answer (score 1):

After you have set the `FlatStyle` to `Flat` you can change the `Backcolor` for each cell. With the `Normal` style you only see a 1 pixel wide frame around the `Button`.

This example creates `DataGridViewButtonCells` and paints these Cells after the DGV has been loaded:

```
for (int r = 0; r < DGV.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    DGV[4, r] = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    ((DataGridViewButtonCell)DGV[4, r]).Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
    ((DataGridViewButtonCell)DGV[4, r]).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;   
    ((DataGridViewButtonCell)DGV[4, r]).Value = r + "RR";
}
```

Your code should be adaptable if you get the hex values right.

Comment: It is already FlatStyle, the problem was with the ColorTranslator ;)